# Rails: How can I let my users choose a design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working with rails and am trying to implement a feature into my blogging application. I would like to have the option to choose a design for my blog. I would of course make the design and code them but after they are coded I would like to have the choice of using one of my designs.

How would/should I approach this?

Comment: I'd first check if any of the existing gems already do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make controller for choosing design form list (of course check vaild of choise). Save choose in session and try this:

In layout:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag @custom_css
```

In application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :check_css

    def check_css
        @custom_css = session[:css]
        @custom_css ||= 'default'
    end
end
```

I think that should work.

Other idea is change to different layout.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout :custom_layout

    def custom_layout
        session[:css].nil? ? session[:css] : 'default'
    end
end
```